# What typical vegetables have pH > 7?

Tags: vegetables

Consider only vegetables typically sold at grocery stores in Canada and UK.

My grandma's dentist has diagnosed her with acid erosion, and counsels her to shun acids. My grandma's trying to be vegan. We're not contemplating "alkaline diets".

Many Google results are wrong. Lemons and limes have pH 2, but [are alleged "moderately akaline".](http://www.ilovenature.world/mindful-living/2017/6/2/what-are-alkaline-foods-and-why-should-you-be-eating-them)

[image]

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong. Eating high pH foods will not balance out the effect of acidic foods on the teeth, and will neither prevent nor reverse dental acid erosion. Follow the dentist’s advice, and focus on avoiding highly acidic foods. Neutral foods should be fine.

Comment: Even though your grandmother wants to be vegan, "I happen to be vegan and have a food question" isn't really topical, even though we consume more vegetables than usual. More importantly, StackExchange is not really suited to "list" questions like this where there are many possible correct answers. Your best bet may be to find a site on Google that _does_ properly categorize items you know to be acidic (e.g. lemons) or alkaline, and use that as your resource.